# how to get name of the swf file which run import my class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some swf files that use  the same class. a  swf name is 2_3.swf ı wan read name and get the numbers to use as variables. How can I do this ? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by swf path. I converted the path to an array then used the last item of the array,

```
  var  swfUrl:String = this.root.loaderInfo.url;
  var urlArr:Array = swfUrl.split("/");
  var start_ind:int = urlArr[urlArr.length - 1].indexOf(".swf");

  var  Num1 = urlArr[urlArr.length - 1].substr((start_ind - 1),1);
  var Num2 = urlArr[urlArr.length - 1].substring(0,1);
  //then convert Num1 and Num2 to int variables
```